# Why YUI3 don't have example of all classess and method like jQuery?

Tags: yui

I planned to use this great library but i guess i was wrong
Inside YUI3 library, For every method and class, there is
no example at all.

I don't know why yahoo make so much documentation without example
of every method and class and even class methods also.

Am i missing something?

I posted [this](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36969#p36969) question and getting no response. and even in stackoverflow also. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796513/how-to-use-find-function-in-yui3-and-how-to-find-meta-tag-list) is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually YUI has excellent documentation. The [User Guides](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/guides/) as well as functional [examples](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/examples/) are available in addition to the [api docs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/)
Is every method everywhere totally documented? No. But they do take pull requests though if you'd like to add to it. Also the best place to ask questions is on the #yui irc channel on freenode.
Also if you are coming from jquery the [rosetta stone](http://www.jsrosettastone.com/) site will help.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for rosetta stone, I was looking to use 'find' method of array class ([link](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Array.html)) and i didn't find any example so i was so upset. Let me see the rosetta stone. might be it can help me.